# How can I use an Android phone as a media player?

Tags: media-player

Is it possible for me to have a central Android phone connected to my old stereo that will let me cast media from any iOS or Android device on my house? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible via mDNS/uPNP/DLNA. You don't even have to use a phone for that. Cheaper variants exist, such as dedicated android-based microcomputers with size of a bigger USB stick.

All you need to do is to install an app that will act as a media player with DLNA support. There are plenty of these available, one such app can be DroidUPnP or Yaacc, both available via [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org). You can then setup the app as a player and control it from a remote controller software, such as ControlDLNA, also available from F-Droid.

Setup is automatic, you just need to fire up a few servers as media sources. These can be computers, xboxes, other phones and pretty much anything that has a DLNA logo on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send music from your devices to your home speakers, check out the new [Chromecast Audio](http://www.google.com/chromecast/speakers/).